# Toggle two rows independently in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

How can I toggle two rows that are in the same table independently. Currently I have two main rows and each main row contains some other rows when I click on any row both the main rows get toggled how can I toggle them independently ?

My HTMl and javascript is as

```
<table id="sort">
    <tr class="nodrag nodrop">
       <td colspan=3><strong><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="toggle">Group 1</a></strong></td>
       <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
   </tr>
        <tr id="1" class="tr_group" style='display:none;'>
            <td style="width:10px;" class="dragHandle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href=# style="margin-left: 20px;">Umair Iqbal</a></td>
            <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999; line-height: 100%;">A Student at TUM</span></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" class="tr_group" style='display:none;'>
            <td style="width:10px;" class="dragHandle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href=# style="margin-left: 20px;">Faryal Khan</a></td>
            <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999; line-height: 100%;">A Doctor at KMC</span></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
        </tr> 

  <tr class="nodrag nodrop">
     <td colspan=3><strong><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="toggle">Group 2</a></strong></td>
     <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
  </tr>
        <tr id="1" class="tr_group" style='display:none;'>
            <td style="width:10px;" class="dragHandle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href=# style="margin-left: 20px;">Umair Iqbal</a></td>
            <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999; line-height: 100%;">A Student at TUM</span></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" class="tr_group" style='display:none;'>
            <td style="width:10px;" class="dragHandle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href=# style="margin-left: 20px;">Faryal Khan</a></td>
            <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999; line-height: 100%;">A Doctor at KMC</span></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
        </tr> 
</table>
```

And the jQuery is

```
<script>
$(".toggle").click(function () {
$(".tr_group").slideToggle('slow');
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the next group of tr elements based on the clicked element.

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil(":not(.tr_group)").slideToggle('slow');
});
```